# MVC w/ JavaScript - trips route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

[See the exception](http://exceptioneer.com/Share/Summary.aspx?81c2baa3-56c5-4250-abe2-35b0c94823e2)

I have a JS include in my master page and it seems to be tripping one of the routes every time.

Is tripping this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"CatalogType",
"Catalog/{group}/{type}/{index}/{browseSize}",
new { controller = "Catalog"
    , action = "Types"
    , group = ""
    , type = ""
    , index = ""
    , browseSize = "" }
);
```

Is there something I can do to stop this behavior?

PS:  I know there is a way to enforce a datatype on these params but for the life of me I cannot find a reference.  Am I dreaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the exception it looks like you're not resolving the virtual path to your javascript file properly on the serverside (i.e. the ~/ bit is ending up being rendered out to the client instead of being resolved into a proper application absoluet path). Where you include your js file you want to include it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/swfobject.js") %>" ></script>
```

Not like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/swfobject.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [overview of route constraints](http://beta.blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/01/11/asp-net-mvc-route-constraints.aspx).

You can also use regular expressions like:

```
routes.MapRoute("CatalogType", "Catalog/{group}/{type}/{index}/{browseSize}",
    new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Types", group = "", type = "", index = "", browseSize = "" },
    new { group = "\w+", browseSize = "\d+" }
);
```

I have found [Phil Haack's route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to be very useful for things like this as well.